# A really long boot time in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS because of "cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated"! Need a fix!

Tags: boot, networking, dmesg

Here is the snippet output of `dmesg`.

```
[   45.760248] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   45.882110] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[  471.007790] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  471.007795] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
[  471.007798] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp), (dfs_cac_time)
[  471.007802] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  471.007806] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  471.007809] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  471.007813] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  471.007817] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 80000 KHz, 160000 KHz AUTO), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  471.007820] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5730000 KHz @ 160000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (0 s)
[  471.007823] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 80000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm), (N/A)
[  471.007826] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm), (N/A)
```

As you can see the time difference while booting is really great. What is **World regulatory domain updated** mean? Is there any way to fix it? Coz I have to wait for around 8 minutes for my system to start up. I would really appreciate your help. Thanks!

Comment: cfg80211 is the [Linux 802.11 configuration API](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/documentation/cfg80211). There seems something wrong with your wireless configuration, especially the [CRDA](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/regulatory/crda), or the firmware of your wireless adapter.

Comment: Check to see that your /etc/default/crda has something like this set up: REGDOMAIN=US, change US to the appropriate country code for you.

Comment: @heynnema
`44.587028] VBoxPciLinuxInit
[   44.664716] vboxpci: IOMMU not found (not registered)
[   81.822964] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[   81.822968] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: unset
`
`[   81.825933] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: IN
[   81.825937] cfg80211:  DFS Master region: JP
`
I got these statements for 3 times, the same ones after I updated the `/etc/default/crda` file.

And the time reduced to _127.xxx_ seconds.

Comment: Do you have IOMMU enabled in your BIOS? This is a guest OS running in Virtualbox? Do other guest OS's take so long to boot also?

Comment: This isn't a guest OS. It's the stand-alone OS on my laptop

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing this issue and it turned out that it seemed to be down to an old modprobe config file (in /etc/modprobe.d) I had installed a few years ago. Specifically it specified an option for the `cfg80211` (WiFi stack module) `options cfg80211 ieee80211_regdom="EU"`

I commented/removed the option then rebooted and it was fixed. So check to see if any of your modprobe.d files contain config options for cfg80211.

Also I noticed that the `REGDOMAIN` was not set in `/etc/default/crda` so I set that. For more details see [Linux Wireless Regulatory info](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/developers/Regulatory).